# Fix the vertical position of `geom_label` in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let say I have below `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 0, 1), y1 = rnorm(100, 10, 1), y2 = rnorm(100, 50, 1))

ggplot(df) +
geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y1)) + 
geom_label(aes(x = mean(range(df$x)), y = 10), label = 'Plot with y', label.padding = unit(.7, 'lines'), fill = '#000000', color = '#ffffff', alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

Now with second variable `y2`, I have below `ggplot`

```
ggplot(df) +
geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y2)) + 
geom_label(aes(x = mean(range(df$x)), y = 10), label = 'Plot with y', label.padding = unit(.7, 'lines'), fill = '#000000', color = '#ffffff', alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

I would like to fix the relative vertical position of the `geom_label` in these two plots, which should be `100 pixels/points` below from the top boundary of my plot area, irrespective of the range on `y axis`.

Is there any option available with `geom_label` to perform the same?

Any pointer will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add your labels as grobs via `annotation_custom` which allows to position your labels using relative coordinates of the plot area. For convenience I use `gridtext::richtext_grob` to create the label grob.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridtext)

set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 0, 1), y1 = rnorm(100, 10, 1), y2 = rnorm(100, 50, 1))

label_grob <- gridtext::richtext_grob(
  text = 'Plot with y',
  x = unit(0.5, "npc"),
  y = unit(1, "npc") - unit(100, "pt"),
  padding = unit(.7, "lines"),
  r = unit(0.15, "lines"),
  gp = grid::gpar(col = '#ffffff'),
  box_gp = grid::gpar(col = '#000000', fill = '#000000', size = 0.25)
)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y1)) + 
  annotation_custom(grob = label_grob)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y2))  + 
  annotation_custom(grob = label_grob)
```

[image]